# Rhino Mocks Assert Property Setter was called with correct object type

Tags: rhino-mocks

I have a method that sets a property

```
public void SetNetworkCredential(string userName, string password, string domain)
{
    _reportExecutionService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
}
```

how do I verify that Credentials was called with a valid NetworkCredential?

I tried this TestMethod but it fails because the NetworkCredential objects are different references

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestTest()
{
    const string userName = "userName";
    const string password = "password";
    const string domain = "domain";

    var mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IReportExecutionService>();
    var rptService= new ReportService(mock);

    rptService.SetNetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);

    mock.AssertWasCalled(x => x.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain));
}
```

Is there a way to validate that the setter was called with an object of type NetworkCredential and with the correct parameters?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I fixed it by making the ReportService accept a Network Credential instead of the username, password, domain

```
public void SetNetworkCredential(NetworkCredential networkCredential)
{
    _reportExecutionService.Credentials = networkCredential;
}
```

so my test was much easier

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestTest()
{
    const string userName = "userName";
    const string password = "password";
    const string domain = "domain";

    var mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IReportExecutionService>();
    var rptService= new ReportService(mock);

    var networkCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);

    rptService.SetNetworkCredential(networkCredential);

    mock.AssertWasCalled(x => x.Credentials = networkCredential);
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer, so this code actually works it tests if setter was called with given value: 

    mock.AssertWasCalled(x => x.PropertyName = VALUE_WE_ARE_CHECKING);

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** Rethinking this problem, my previous suggested answer would probably not work. Here's why:

Essentially, you are attempting to verify that the dependency of a dependency has been set up correctly. That is probably why you are having problems writing a unit test for this. You probably want to consider whether it would make sense for you to move the `SetNetworkCredential` method into the class that implements `IReportExecutionService` instead.

And if you do, the unit test for that method would be simple enough:

```
[Test]
public void TestSetNetworkCredential()
{
    const string userName = "userName";
    const string password = "password";
    const string domain = "domain";

    var rptService= new ReportExecutionService();

    rptService.SetNetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
    Assert.AreEqual(userName, rptService.Credentials.UserName);
    Assert.AreEqual(password, rptService.Credentials.Password);
    Assert.AreEqual(domain, rptService.Credentials.Domain);
}
```

Comment: That would be ideal for sure. But the class that implements IReportExecutionService is a code generated class (WSDL to SSRS), I extracted the IReportExecutionService so that I could mock it.